# How can I insert images in a sql table

Tags: python, html, sql, flask

Hi everyone and thanks in advance, I wanted to ask how I can insert images in a sql table. I have to use flask for websites. Thank you

Comment: you don't store images in a database. Use a folder and save the files there. What functionnality do you want to implement, what service does your server may offer ?

Comment: [Storing Images in DB - Yea or Nay?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3748/3890632)

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to not store the image directly in the database. Rather it would be better to have the `file path` for the image in the database. If the image is external, then a link to the image. Database storage is more expensive than having the image in a filesystem. In addition, you don't need any special type of code to access images in filesystems.

Credit, and for further help: [Storing Images in DB - Yea or Nay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay)

Comment: hi, thank you very much, could you tell me how you would do it specifically since i don't have much experience with sql? Thanks again

Comment: Hi, I'm not completely good with this type of setup, especially with `Flask`. You can probably look up `how to send images to server using Flask` and then figure out how to use that image to store into `file path`.